# What is idiomatic (a.k.a. "right") way to pass set (or at least list) of ints as a template argument in D?

Tags: d, template-meta-programming

I need to pass a set of ints or list of ints to a class as a template argument. I can do this via Andrei Alexandrescu's type list as in C++. But I think it is heavyweight solution. Is there any idiomatic (more D-ish) way to do this in D?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be you need provide more complete description, but as far as I can see you may use:

```
class T(int[] C){
   this(){
      writeln("Array: ", C);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that arrays can be used as template arguments. Thanks!

Comment: Basically thing can be used

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to use variadic parameters:

```
struct T(A...) {
}
T!(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) object;
```